# url pattern not working

Tags: url, servlets, filter

I am a newbie in java web programming and my boss have assigned me with a difficult task(for me).We have a html form hosted in tomcat server and it is submitted to a php page in different server.Now my boss wants to add captcha in the form but dont want to authenticate in php page.So i thought may be i will implement a filter and authenticate it there.

```
<form action="http://differentproject.com/display.php" method="Post">
            <input type="text" name="text"></input>
            <input type="Submit" value="submit"/>
        </form>
```

so lets consider above is my html page and form is submitted to display.php.I want to intercept it with a filter but the following url pattern wont work.

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>test</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>http://differentproject.com/display.php</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

neither does this,

```
<filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>test</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/display.php</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>
```

I think its not working because url is out of project scope.Can it be made to work?

Answer (score 1):

```
it is submitted to a php page in different server
```

You can only filter or intercept this on the different server (the php server, not the tomcat server) because as soon as the user submits the form, the browser makes a request to the different server. Your tomcat server is not involved anymore.

You would either need to

- change the original form to no longer submit to the different server
- get the php server to redirect the request to where you want it to go